# ASP.NET MVC 3: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, nullreferenceexception

I have generated a strongly-type view from a model class that I have created from scratch. I have used the `List` as the scaffold template. The error appears at the `foreach` line with the `model` object.

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<HockeyPoolStats.Models.Player>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team_Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rank)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerTeam)
        </td>
[...]
```

**Controller:**

```
 public class PlayerController : Controller
    {

        private HockeyPoolStatsDB _db = new HockeyPoolStatsDB();

        //
        // GET: /Player/


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Player _player = new Player();
        _db.Players.Add(_player);
        var model = _db.Players;

        return View(model);
    }

    }
```

**DbContext**

```
public class HockeyPoolStatsDB : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Goalie> Goalies { get; set; }


    }
```

I don't understand why `model` is null. This means that the controller isn't passing the model to the view correctly?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hello, first of all using DbSet<T> member on view is not good idea, ı think that you should wrap user interface modal with them because they are proxies elements. because context will be terminate when finish produce razor page.. and you will lost data context.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: ok. please try to modify your code as  var model = _db.Players.ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It more likely means that `_db.Players` is returning null.

Set a breakpoint and step through it and verify that `_db.Players` is actually returning a list of players.

Comment: I tried adding a player to the DbSet and it still gives me the same error (see edit above)

Comment: @JFB, can you post the relevant parts of HockeyPoolStatsDB?

Comment: I added the HockeyPoolStatsDB.

Comment: proxy elements should not pass view.

Comment: What is so complicated? I am simply trying to pass the model to the view using the controller and the model is always null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JFB, it's hard to tell. The code itself looks fine, but to be honest I'm not familiar with the DbContext class. If you set a breakpoint on the `var model = _db.Players` what is the result of _db.Players? Is it 1 player or is it a null DbSet?

Comment: Even with a breakpoint in the controller, the compiler doesnt stop and crashes in the view. (see screenshot) and model is null... I dont know if there is a null DbSet

Comment: @JFB, the controller has to be called in order to render the view. Are you sure you're debugging properly? Or that you're looking at the correct action method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure... I have set a break point in the Index() method of the controller. BUT, I have not called the controller. Isnt't the controller called by the view using `@Html.ActionLink` ?

Comment: @JFB, The controller is called when the page gets loaded. Routing will handle all of that. When you set the breakpoint and start debugging, does the breakpoint say anything? It is a solid red dot, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's a solid red dot on the line: `var model = _db.Players.ToList();`. I'm guessing the controller never gets called and the view gets generated first.

Comment: @JFB, we've gotten horribly off topic. It might be best if you take your RegisterRoutes method in the Global.asax, controller code, etc. and ask a different question about why your controller is not being hit. Once you're able to start debugging, you'll have a better chance of solving this issue.

Comment: AH! I've found out why: I was using something else than the HomeController. I moved the code to the `Index()` in HomeController and it worked. Thanks!